# How to get MySQL time fraction with Devart dotConnect Express MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, devart

Assume that I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date,
  `timestamp2` timestamp(2),
  `datetime3` datetime(3),
  `time6` time(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Here's the sample inserts:

```
insert into table1(`date`,`timestamp2`,datetime3,time6)
values('2000-01-01','2001-01-01 01:01:01.23',
       '2002-01-01 01:01:01.243','01:01.234893');

insert into table1(`date`,`timestamp2`,datetime3,time6) 
values(null,null,null,null);
```

and I get the data in C# like this:

```
using Devart.Data.MySql;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnString))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from table1;";
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
    }
}

int row = 0;

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    row++;

    sb.AppendLine();
    sb.AppendLine("Row " + row);

    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        object ob = dr[dc.ColumnName];
        string typeName = ob.GetType().ToString();
        sb.AppendLine($"{dc.ColumnName} = {typeName} | value = " + ob + "");
    }
}

richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

and here's the output:

```
Row 1
id = System.Int64 | value = 1
date = System.DateTime | value = 01/01/2000 12:00:00 AM
timestamp2 = System.DateTime | value = 01/01/2001 1:01:01 AM
datetime3 = System.DateTime | value = 01/01/2002 1:01:01 AM
time6 = System.TimeSpan | value = 01:01:00.2348930

Row 2
id = System.Int64 | value = 2
date = System.DBNull | value = 
timestamp2 = System.DBNull | value = 
datetime3 = System.DBNull | value = 
time6 = System.DBNull | value =
```

As you can see that the Devart Express dotConnect MySQL returns time fraction in `DateTime` in C#. The time fraction is lost.

How to get the time fraction?

*Note: For some reason I must use Devart Express dotConnect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fractional second values are stored in DataTime structure.

Kindly note, that the default ToString method of DateTime doesn't show the fraction of a second.

To extract the string representation of a time's millisecond component, call the date and time value's [DateTime.ToString(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring#system-datetime-tostring(system-string)) or [ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tostring) method, and pass the fff or FFF custom format pattern alone or with other custom format specifiers as the format parameter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-display-milliseconds-in-date-and-time-values.

To see the time fraction in your test application:

```
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
    var ob = dr[dc.ColumnName];
    string typeName = ob.GetType().ToString();

    string val;
    if (typeName == "System.DateTime") val = ((DateTime)ob).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd hh: mm:ss.fff");
    else val = ob.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine($"{dc.ColumnName} = {typeName} | value = " + val + "");
}
```

The result:

```
Row 1
id = System.Int64 | value = 1
date = System.DateTime | value = 2000.01.01 12: 00:00.000
timestamp2 = System.DateTime | value = 2001.01.01 01: 01:01.230
datetime3 = System.DateTime | value = 2002.01.01 01: 01:01.243
time6 = System.TimeSpan | value = 01:01:00.2348930
 
Row 2
id = System.Int64 | value = 2
date = System.DBNull | value =
timestamp2 = System.DBNull | value =
datetime3 = System.DBNull | value =
time6 = System.DBNull | value =
Press any key to continue . . .
```